# RegExp in Teradata 13

Tags: regex, teradata, translate

I have field VEH_NUM as `SxS2625K` and I need to convert to only numeric field as `2625`

I have the following query which executes in TD 15

```
SELECT
VEH_NUM,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(VEH_NUM, '[0-9]+') as VEHICLE_NUM,
oTranslate(VEH_NUM,oTranslate(VEH_NUM,'0123456789',''),'') as REG_NUM
FROM DATABASE.TABLENAME
```

But need them in TD13. The veh_Num  can be `SPB99B` or `SPB9B` . I just need to remove all alphabets.

Comment: TD13 is an anncient version, neither `RegEx` nor `oTranslate` are builtin. `oTranslate` is available as addon (part of the Oracle UDFs which are builtin since TD13.10), but probably not installed at your site.

Comment: @dnoeth is there any way i can achieve this in TD13. We moved to TD15, but need this in TD13.

Comment: You can ask your DBA to install `oTranslate`. Or do some brute force checking each character: `case when substr(VEH_NUM,1,1) between '0' and '9' then substr(VEH_NUM,1,1) else '' end || case when substr(VEH_NUM,2,1)... ` This is not bad (just a lot of cut&paste) if the source column is not too long).